# My apt-get installer has no autocompletion for some packages

Tags: bash, apt, kali-linux, autocomplete

I have installed **Kali Linux** v1.1.0 (Debian based).
**Filename completion** for sudo was not running at the beginning, so I added:

```
complete -c sudo
```

And everything seems to **autocomplete** now, except for some packages in the **apt-get** package manager. If I type:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lubuntu-des
```

... and I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> :

```
$ sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

... the package name "lubuntu-desktop" is autocompleted.

But if I type:

```
$  sudo apt-get install hwi
```

... this time <kbd>TAB</kbd> does not autocomplete to `hwinfo` as it must, even when the package does *exist* on the repos. If I complete the word manually:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install hwinfo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
hwinfo is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
```

I have checked this behavior in another machine running Kali Linux too, and the autocompletion works OK for every package.

This is really nagging, as long as, if autocompletion works only sometimes, you can not know if a requested package does really exist in the repositories.

A strange behavior. This line:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sourc
```

autocompletes to:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

even when the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file exist.

This is inside my `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` :

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

but not inside my `/etc/profile`.

Why is this happening and **how can I solve** it?

EDIT-01: Tested adding `complete -c sudo` to `~/.bashrc`. Still not solved.

EDIT-02: It seems there is no difference between installed or not installed programs. The package `partimage` is not installed, and does not autocomplete with <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Comment: Do you have `lubuntu-desktop` package installed?

Comment: @Braiam: No, it is not.